# Joomla 1.5 admin section blank

Tags: joomla, administration

I've just installed Joomla 1.5.22, and after I log into Joomla admin, the Joomla logo appears, and the content area with rounded corners appears, but there is no content, and no admin menus.

I've uploaded the /administrator folder once more, but the problem remains.

I've searched the Joomla forums without much luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla was simply reinstalled, which resolved this problem.